# sax xml display one item at a time randomly

Tags: java, android

hIw'm using a sax parser and instead of listing everything I want to pull one record at a time. Here is my xml that I'm pulling from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>Conservation Tips</title>
    <link>blah</link>
    <description>Living comfortably during a Memphis summer can be challenging, but it   does not have to be costly. What are some of the easiest ways to stay cool and save?</description>
    <item>
        <title>Have a professional, reputable contractor clean and inspect your air conditioner. This should be done every year, whether you have window or central units.</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Set the thermostat at 78 degrees or higher for the most energy efficient operation. Each degree below this setting adds 6% to your cooling costs.</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Check your air conditioner's filter every time you receive your utility bill.</title>
        </item>
    <item>
        <title>Use fans to move the air inside your home. This gives the sensation that it is 5 degrees cooler than the actual temperature.</title>
        </item>
    <item>
        <title>Shade windows on the sunny side of your home.</title>
        </item>
    <item>
        <title>Keep drapes closed or add room-darkening shades to block out the heat from the sun.</title>
        </item>
    <item>
        <title>The outside portion of a central air conditioner is the condensing unit. Keep it clear from dried mud, debris and grass clippings, because it needs to breathe.</title>
        </item>
    <item>
        <title>Use your programmable thermostat to automatically increase the temperature setting at bedtime.</title>
        </item>
    <item>
        <title>Sleep under lightweight bedding and use fans during sleep.</title>
        </item>
    <item>
        <title>Do not place lamps near your thermostat. The thermostat senses the heat produced from the lamp and causes the air conditioner to run longer than necessary.</title>
        </item>
    <item>
        <title>Do not set your thermostat at a colder setting than normal when you turn on your air conditioner. It will not cool your home any faster and could result in excessive cooling and, therefore, unnecessary expense.</title>
        </item>
</channel>
```

and here is the code that I have

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    try {
        url = new URL("url");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    RssFeed feed = null;
    try {
        feed = RssReader.read(url);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<RssItem> rssItems = feed.getRssItems();
    for(RssItem rssItem : rssItems) {
        Log.i("RSS Reader", rssItem.getTitle());
        //Log.i(rssItem.getTitle(), rssItem.getDescription());
        //Log.i("RSS Content", rssItem.getLink());
    }
}}
```

What I'm trying to do is show one item at a time randomly. I can pull them all but can't seem to get one at a time. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't do random access with a SAX parser. You could use a DOM parser instead which would give you random access capability, or you could simply get all the items and then only handle one chosen at random, that is:

```
ArrayList<RssItem> rssItems = feed.getRssItems();

Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

//Pick one at random
Log.i("RSS Reader", rssItems.get(rand.nextInt(rssItems.size())).getTitle();
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the RssItems in a map with keys starting from 1 to numberOfRssItems. Then use the random number generator to generate a number between 1 and numberOfRssItems and get that record from the map using the random number as the key.